# How to add Roles in AppInsight Access control using ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to add Role Assignment in AppInsight Access control using ARM template.
I am able to create AppInsight with ARM template but unable to move ahead with addition of Role Assignment in App Insight Access control . Following is my code for creation of App Insight using ARM template

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
        "kind": "web",
        "name": "[parameters('components_AppInsightPoc_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
        "location": "westus2",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "Application_Type": "web",
            "Flow_Type": "Redfield",
            "Request_Source": "IbizaAIExtension",
            "HockeyAppId": null,
            "SamplingPercentage": null
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to add roles in app insight access control using ARM template

Comment: define "roles"? RBAC roles?

Comment: Yes , I want to add roles using ARM template

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template#example-template-to-create-a-role-assignment , this is for resource group scope, just change the scope for your appinsight

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to add RBAC roles to the resource:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('components_AppInsightPoc_name'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', guid('something'))]",
    "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'role_guid')]",
        "principalId": "user_guid",
        "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('components_AppInsightPoc_name'))"
    }
}
```

you can get role guids with powershell:

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for input , can you just let me know , what value is expected in guid('something')

Comment: anything, it just needs to be unique if you want to generate a new guid

Comment: Can we just paas the AppInsight Name ?

Comment: I am getting the following error

'Authorization failed for template resource 'DevopsTestAppInsight/Microsoft.Authorization/caa36d20-9bcc-5e25-abbc-5a33af20ad40' of type 'Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments'. The client 'c75534ba-5ced-447d-affe-247dc70c063f' with object id 'c75534ba-5ced-447d-affe-247dc70c063f' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope '/subscriptions/0000000000/resourceGroups/TestRgDevops/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/DevopsTestAppInsight/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments

Comment: I have passed following values
guid('something') : In something , I passed the AppInsight name itself
'role_guid' : I have passed guid for Reader role (acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7)
user_guid : I have principal Id of my aad app over here

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong over here

Comment: raise a new question for this, its a permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

Able to add RBAC for App Insights with the following code

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('AppInsightName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid('AppInsightName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables(parameters('builtInRoleType'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer on this question: [Apply Azure RBAC to resource using ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340455/apply-azure-rbac-to-a-resource-using-arm/64247322#64247322)

I have an array of Role IDs that I wanted to add as Owners at the App Insight resource, without making the users Owners at the Resource Group level. I didn't want to use the nested resource approach as I wanted to iterate over an array of objects to dynamically create the roles, so after tweaking the type, name, and scope attributes, the following resource block is what ended up working for me:

```
    {
      "comments": "Add the Application Insights resource",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "ApplicationId": "[variables('appInsightsName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "comments": "Add the IAM roles to the App Insights resource",
      "condition": "[parameters('isProduction')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments",
      "name": "[concat(variables('appInsightsName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid(parameters('roleAssignments')[copyIndex()].principalId))]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635')]", // Owner Role
        "principalId": "[parameters('roleAssignments')[copyIndex()].principalId]",
        "scope": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "appInsightsRoleAssignments",
        "count": "[length(parameters('roleAssignments'))]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
      ]
    }
```

Pay close attention to the segments in the *type, name, and scope* properties of the **Microsoft.Insights/components/providers/roleAssignments** resource.